# Text file possibly corrupted

Tags: latex, file-corruption, textmate

I have a .tex (LaTeX) file that now ends basically like this when I open it in a text editor (VS Code / Textmate):

`we may write $x=\ep\x73\x20\x65\x64\x67\x65\x20\x24\x65\x5F\x69\x24\x20\x63\x6F\x6E\x6E\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x24\x76\x5F\x69\x24\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x73\x6F\x6D\x65\x20\x24\x76\x5F\x6A\x24\x2C\x20\x24\x6A\x3C\x69\x2<NUL>`

I can turn the ASCII codes back into regular text, but there are some lines missing after the `<NUL>`.

(I had been using the laptop and closed it (folded it) and put it away. When I reopened it hours later this one file was corrupt. I didn't lose much (maybe nothing) because I had pushed it to git a few days before. But I am of course wondering if it will happen again.)

> Is it a sign of wear and tear for the computer or its disk drive, or something else?

Comment: Do the "ASCII codes" always look like `\xAB` codes in _any_ editor that you open the file with?

Comment: @user1686 It looked like that in Textmate and VS Code. Didn't try any others...